# How to let fetchmail play a sound when it's done fetching emails?

Tags: fetchmail

How to let fetchmail play a sound when it's done fetching emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `ffmpeg` installed, you can use it to play a sound of almost any filetype:

```
ffplay -nodisp /path/to/sound/file
```

Unfortunately that will spawn a window in most versions of `ffmpeg` included with Linux distributions, though it has been fixed in the latest version.  If that's undesirable, you can also use the `aplay` command, but that can only play WAV, AU and other raw audio formats:

```
aplay /path/to/sound.wav
```

If you don't want to have to type that every time, you can write a little script to do it for you.  Just drop a file like this to somewhere like `~/bin/fetchsound` and make it excuatable (`chmod +x ~/bin/fetchsound`):

```
#!/bin/bash

fetchmail [..]

if [ $? -le 1 ]; then
    ffplay -nodisp /path/to/sounds/success.ogg
else
    ffplay -nodisp /path/to/sounds/failure.ogg
fi
```

You could also just have it play a sound when you have new mail, because `fetchmail` returns a `0` exit code when it downloads new mail and `1` when it doesn't.  (All other status codes indicate a failure.)

```
#!/bin/bash

fetchmail [..]

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    ffplay -nodisp /path/to/sounds/newmail.ogg
elif [ $? -gt 1 ]; then
    ffplay -nodisp /path/to/sounds/failure.ogg
fi
```

Comment: The problem is I run fetchmail in daemon mode like 
`fetchmail --keep --verbose --ssl --fetchlimit 0 --fetchsizelimit 0 
--timeout 45 --daemon 180 --fetchmailrc ${HOME}/.fetchmailrc-pop`
Will your solution work after each 180 second interval?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running it in the foreground:

```
fetchmail ...; printf '\a'
```